# MoinMoin acl on a page doesnt work

Tags: moinmoin

In `wikiconfig.py` I have

```
acl_rights_before = u"Adminuser:read,write,delete,revert,admin +ReaderGroup:read +EditorGroup:read,write,delete,revert"
acl_rights_default = u"All:"
```

But I have some pages, that I want to make unreadable to anyone expect EditorGroup.
I was trying to make that with on page acl line :

```
#acl EditorGroup:read,write,revert,delete ReaderGroup:
```

but users, who are members of ReaderGroup still can access that page.... 
Can anyone tell me, where I am doing a mistake?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The rights defined in `acl_rights_before` cannot be overwritten, thus whoever has rights defined in `acl_rights_before` will have it regardless of what is defined later.

If you want to be able to overwrite the rights for some group or user in the `#acl`-directive of the page, the right has to be defined in `acl_rights_default`.

Moving the rights to `acl_rights_default` in wikiconfig.py

```
acl_rights_default = u"Adminuser:read,write,delete,revert,admin ReaderGroup:read EditorGroup:read,write,delete,revert All:"
```

and on the page remove all rights for the ReaderGroup and keep the rest "Default":

```
#acl ReaderGroup: Default
```

if you have other groups it seems easier to me to just define the rights for the EditorGroup explicitly on the page (all others, except acl_rights_before will be overwritten)

```
#acl EditorGroup:read,write,delete,revert
```